# can open website in browser but not in python

Tags: python, python-requests

Trying to get data from below url . it is working in browser but not in python

```
import requests
url = 'https://www.nseindia.com/api/live-analysis-variations?index=gainers&type=NIFTY'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105'} # This is chrome, you can set whatever browser you like
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(response.status_code)
print(response.text)
```

output i get is -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Resource not found</title>
</head>
<body style="background-color: #e8e8e8;">
  <div style="font-size: 32px; padding: 50px 25px; text-align: center;">
    Resource not found
  </div>
</body>
</html>

401
```

Comment: Your link doesn't work in my browser (Chrome on Windows).

Comment: If you want to open a link in your browser you should better use the module webbrowser.

Comment: Might consider copying the request your browser makes as a cURL and using the code generated by [this tool](https://curlconverter.com/).

Comment: thanks  . @aquamaru its working. i did not know about the tool

Comment: I see same error in browser (Resource not found).